# Values from hiddenfield shows very slowly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a question. How can I improve speed of getting values in this script below?
My script sets a 170 markers, later gets a values lng and lat of map bounds when map is in change (idle event) and send this values into hiddenfield. For 10-20-30 markers, this values are showing very fast, but for +100 markers, this function is very slow, and it takes a 5-6 sec to show all values when map is change.. I'm using marker clusterer, but there is no effect in speed. How to improve this?
greetings !

```
                (..) // map options
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapka"), mapOptions);

                var markers = [];

                var lngstring = <%=lngstring %>
                var latstring = <%=latstring %>
                //alert(latstring);
                //alert(lngstring);
                var arraylat = latstring.split("#");
                var arraylng = lngstring.split("#");

                for (var i = 0; i < arraylng.length-1; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(arraylng[i], arraylat[i])
                    });
                markers.push(marker);
                }
                var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);

                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
                var bounds = map.getBounds();
                var nelat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
                var nelng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
                var swlat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
                var swlng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
                var c1 = map.getCenter().lat();
                var c2 = map.getCenter().lng();
                var zoom1 = map.getZoom();
                document.getElementById("<%=hfNelat.ClientID%>").value = nelat;
                document.getElementById("<%=hfNelng.ClientID%>").value = nelng;
                document.getElementById("<%=hfSwlat.ClientID%>").value = swlat;
                document.getElementById("<%=hfSwlng.ClientID%>").value = swlng;
                document.getElementById("<%=UpdateButton1.ClientID %>").click();
                });
```

Code "behind":

```
    protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lNelat.Text = hfNelat.Value;
        lNelng.Text = hfNelng.Value;
        lSwlat.Text = hfSwlat.Value;
        lSwlng.Text = hfSwlng.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are loading the markers statically in the page.  The page would load faster if you were to load the markers using AJAX techniques (asynchronously).

See the [The AJAX Philosophy page](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic11.htm) from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial.

Comment: I need to load only once markers from database, draw all of them on map and that's all with markers - other job is with bounds values, and I need to get this values as fast as it is possible, without 10 sec waiting (2-3 sec wait is acceptable of course). AJAX will improve this waiting time? Honestly, I never use AJAX and I don't know how to introduce it on my script. Could you say something more about this solution with loading markers using ajax?

Comment: Did you read Mike Williams' page?  If that didn't help, try [this](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=AJAX+Asynchronous+Javascript+and+Xml), but it won't reduce the time to get the results, just the time to display the map.  The issue is that putting all the marker information statically in your page increases the size of your page and therefor the time it takes to render.